# Windows Azure File storage perfermance

Tags: azure-storage, azure-files

Is there a solution to get the below informations of Window File Azure storage Account using Windows Azure Storage Client Library:

1. Azure Storage Account  Capacity
2. Azure Storage Free and used Space
3. Azure Storage Account State (Active, Disable, Enable ….)
4. Client Transfer files (Mo, GO … ) per month, days …
5. Azure Storage Account Performance
6. ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a azure standard account contains multiple services. Blob, table, queue, file.

If you want to know the information about he file service, you could use Windows Azure Storage Client Library. If you want to know the information about your storage account, I suggest you could use azure management library.

> Azure Storage Account Capacity

As far as I know, the azure storage account capacity is 500TB.

Max size of a file share is 5TB.

Max size of a file is 1TB.

We could create multiple file share in one storage account. The only limit is the 500 TB storage account capacity.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-scalability-targets).

> Azure Storage Free and used Space

As far as I know, we could only get the quota and usage of a fileshare by using the Windows Azure Storage Client Library.

We could use CloudFileShare.Properties.Quota property to get the quota of the fileshare and use CloudFileShare.GetStats method to get the usage of the fileshare.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
     "connectionstring");
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();


            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("fileshare");

            share.FetchAttributes();
            //get the quota
            int? i = share.Properties.Quota;
           //get usage
            var re =  share.GetStats();
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.WriteLine(re.Usage);
```

> Azure Storage Account State (Active, Disable, Enable ….)

As far as I know, we couldn't get storage account state by using storage SDK. If you want to get this value, I suggest you could use azure management library. You could install it from Nuget package. You could get the [StorageAccount.Properties.Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.storage.models.storageaccountproperties.aspx) from the [StorageAccounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.storage.models.storageaccount.aspx) class.

More details about how to use azure management library to access the storage account you could refer to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722415.aspx).

> Client Transfer files (Mo, GO … ) per month, days …

As far as I know, the Windows Azure Storage Client Library doesn't contain the method to get the client transfer files (Mo, GO … ) per month, days.

Here is a workaround, you could write codes to calculate the transfer files number in your application and store this number to azure table storage per day.(When uploading the file to the azure file storage, firstly get the number from the table and add one, then upload the number to the table storage)

If you want to get the number of the transfer files, you could use the azure table storage SDK to get the result.

> Azure Storage Account Performance

As far as I know, if we want to check our azure storage account performance, we should firstly enable the diagnostics to log how the storage works. Then we could check the storage performance by using its service's metrics.

More details about how to access metrics data by using Windows Azure Storage Client Library. I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/enabling-storage-metrics-and-viewing-metrics-data#accessing-metrics-data-programmatically).